# Monitor Samsung s22a300b not correctly recognized

Tags: drivers

I've a new monitor Samsung s22a300b and I downloaded the driver from Samsung's website.

Driver: SMS22A300B.exe

When I run the driver it wants me to select the monitor which I want to install, the problem is, the only option there is for the s20a300b which is a smaller, lower resolution monitor. Since this is the only option I install it. Then windows in the control panel also recognizes this monitor as the s20a300b and so the maximally permitted resolution is limited to 1600x900 instead of the Full HD(1080p).

Ironically the monitor worked fine the first time, when I plugged it in before installing the driver. The problems started after I switched the DPI setting from 120 to 96(normal size) and rebooted.

Is this a driver problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it updating the driver as in:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/pnp_driver_support.mspx?mfr=true